# TinyMCE how to dynamically get line breaks in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-4

I need advice on how I can create dynamic line breaks ideally with an `<li>` inside TINY. I have tried using an each loop and also a for loop, and the values just do not appear in the text area. BUT, if I just add them to the text area with a val() they go in fine, BUT as just one long string.

The text area has an id of wo_materials. I'm successfully getting my text into Tiny like this:

```
        $('#wo_materials').val(materials);

        tinymce.init({
            selector:'textarea'
        });
```

And I get a nice row of text values:

[image: Values in TinyMCE]

The materials value is an array. If I look at it in the console it looks like this:

```
0: BP #15 Plain Felt 36" 
1:  Duraflo Weatherpro 50 
2:  1 1/4 Coil Nails - box
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. The secret is adding the incrementing var "text" to the for loop and then wrapping the object / array in an `<li>`

```
var materials= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('materials'));
var text=" "; 
materials.length;
function workorders(){
            for (i = 0; i < materials.length; i++) {
               text += "<li>"+materials[i]+"</li>";
            }
            $('#wo_materials').val("<li>"+text+"</li>");
        }

        workorders();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only modifying the value of the text area before tinymce is initialized then this might work for you:

```
$('#wo_materials).val(materials.join('<br/>'));
```